# Disable reopening windows after forced restart on updates

Tags: windows-7

We have our computers in domain and the windows updates are managed by the domain administrator.

So when these updates are installed (at night) the computer is forced to restart after that. When I come back in the morning and log in, Windows starts reopening all the applications I have left open the day before.

This takes about *10 minutes* before I can do *anything* with the system again.

So my question is: is there any way to disable autoloading these apps on startup? (I'm still a local admin on that machine.)